# Product but with Dot operation

Tags: functions, dot

I want to describe a way to express a chain of Dot Product like this:

```
m[13].m[12].m[11].m[10].m[9].m[8].m[7].m[6]
```

Something like

```
comp[i,j]=m[j].m[j-1]...m[i+1].m[i]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
comp[i_, j_] := Array[m, 1 + j - i, {j - 1, i}, Dot]
comp[3, 8]
```

> m[8].m[7].m[6].m[5].m[4].m[3]

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
Dot @@ m /@ Range[13, 6, -1]
```

?